# How to convert C code for old Visual Studio 2005, especially the TinyExpr source code

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to convert the source code of 
TinyExpr (https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr) in
a C compatible code for Visual Studio 2005 ( I think it is 
C89/90 compliant).
In particular I have a problem to convert this macro in ( present in tinyexpr.c ):

```
#define NEW_EXPR(type, ...) new_expr((type), (const te_expr*[]){__VA_ARGS__})
```

with:

```
typedef struct te_expr {
    int type;
    union {double value; const double *bound; const void *function;};
    void *parameters[1];
} te_expr;

static te_expr *new_expr(const int type, const te_expr *parameters[]) {
 ...
}

static te_expr *base(state *s) {
  ...
}
```

The problem arise in the calling: `NEW_EXPR(TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, base(s));`
where I have a :

> error C2059: sintax error : '{'

Comment: The expression `(const te_expr*[]){__VA_ARGS__}` is a [*compound literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), and there's really no nice way to backport that feature as used in the macro for old pre-C99 compilers. VS2005 is getting very old by now, and there are free variants of more modern and up-to-date Visual Studio versions that handle C99 much better. Please consider to update Visual Studio.

Comment: Also for future questions please copy-paste the actual error message you get, in full and complete. Don't retype it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the advice, but at the moment I can't update visual studio, the software must be able to work on visual studio 2005

Comment: Actually, it's not possible *at all* in older compilers, as vararg macros and `__VA_ARGS__` is a C99 addition. You could make a new vararg *function* `new_expr_va` where you pass a null-terminated list of `te_expr *` arguments, and which creates the array and calls the real `new_expr` function, but there's no way to create a macro like the one shown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please put the code in the answer so that I can accept it, for me it is not important that it is a macro, I can replace it with any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment there's really no nice way to do this in older compiler.

One possible way is to use a wrapper vararg function, which creates the array dynamically, call the real `new_expr` function, and then free's the temporary array.

Perhaps something like

```
te_expr *new_expr_va(const int type, ...) {
    re_expr *result = NULL;  /* The resulting expression structure to return */
    size_t argument_count = 0;  /* The number of te_expr arguments passed */

    /*
     * We do two passes over the arguments, once to get the number of them,
     * and once to get the actual values.
     */

    /* First get the number of arguments */
    {
        va_list va;

        va_start(va, type);

        /* Loop until we get a null pointer */
        while (va_arg(va, te_expr *) != NULL)
            ++argument_count;

        va_end(va);
    }

    /* Now allocate the array */
    te_expr **parameters = malloc(argument_count * sizeof(te_expr *));

    /* And populate the array */
    {
        va_list va;
        size_t index = 0;
        te_expr *expr;

        va_start(va, type);

        /* Get all arguments and add to the allocated array */
        while ((expr = va_arg(va, te_expr *)) != NULL)
            parameters[index++] = expr;

        va_end(va);
    }

    /* Now we call the actual function */
    result = new_expr(type, parameters);

    /* Free the memory we allocated for the array */
    free(parameters);

    /* And return the result */
    return result;
}
```

Can be used such as

```
/* Argument list must be terminated by a NULL */
new_expr_va(TE_FUNCTION1 | TE_FLAG_PURE, base(s), NULL);
```

Note that this is all untested and doesn't have any kind of error checking.

Comment: I've tried you code, but I have this error:
1>.\tinyexpr.c(117) : warning C4013: 'va_start' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>.\tinyexpr.c(120) : warning C4013: 'va_arg' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>.\tinyexpr.c(120) : error C2275: 'te_expr': illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: I'm sorry I'm missing #include <stdarg.h>, 
but " 1>.\tinyexpr.c(120) : error C2275: 'te_expr': illegal use of this type as an expression"  error remains